# Creating Dynamic Parent Child drop downs from a JSON feed with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

I'm trying to create a parent child drop down style of selector similar to this fiddle example here [Check it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/2uh3Q/2/).

The issue that I'm having is my JSON doesn't return a paraent ID within the child like in this example used.  For reference here is my JSON below:

[http://plnkr.co/edit/ia3hqKojbZZH6dAJ0ZFz](http://plnkr.co/edit/ia3hqKojbZZH6dAJ0ZFz?p=preview)

As you can see, there is a main link that starts as the main parent.  With in there you get the starting categories.  More then likely this would be something like:

```
Sports
    - soccer
Adademics
    - math
```

The other categories could have sub children as well, but I really only need the first two levels of the hierachy and after that point I could list the sub children as as simply indents in the second level.  My pain point is how I connect the parent with the child without a reference in the child to the parent.  For example in my JSON from the plunkr I would like to take the parent Events and after it is selected populate the second drop down with Granduation, Homecoming, Prom, and Spirituality.

```
Events
    - Prom
    - Homecoming
    - Graduation
    - Spirituality
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by using the whole object as `ng-model` instead of using the `id`. This is an example markup:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedParent" 
          ng-change="selectedChild=null"
          ng-options="p as p.name for p in items">
      <option value="">-- Choose Parent --</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="selectedChild" ng-disabled="!selectedParent" 
          ng-change="selectedGrandchild=null"
          ng-options="c as c.name for c in selectedParent.children">
    <option value="">-- Choose Child --</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="selectedGrandchild" ng-disabled="!selectedChild" 
          ng-options="gc as gc.name for gc in selectedChild.children">
    <option value="">-- Choose Grandchild --</option>
  </select>
```

Here is a working plunk as an example (I used the data provided in the plunk): http://plnkr.co/S5RCMv

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense!  However if I go this route and the goal is to pass the latest ID of the selection to a form (in my case formData.cat_id how can I do this if the model contains everything?  The hard part seems to be how I would then only take the last ID select from the last drop down selection and pass that to the form.

Comment: If you only need the ID from the last dropdown, you can change the `ng-options` of the last dropdown as such: `ng-options="gc.id as gc.name for gc in selectedChild.children"`. This way the `selectedGrandchild` will contain the ID instead of the whole object.

Comment: I would need the ID of which ever select item was the last to be selected.  For instace if the user only went to the first drop down and picked Academy and no other drop downs were used I would only take the ID from there and send it with the form.  However if they selected Academy and then Events from the second drop down, I would only need to send the ID from Events.  So its really the last ID that't been selected in general.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct or not, but I figured it out by setting up a watcher collection.  Seens to be working well!

Comment: You should try to avoid watch expressions, they can slow things down. What you can also do is before submitting the data just check which model is set starting from the grandchild and add that id to the object.

Comment: How terrible is that performance hit though?  On a page with only 1 watcher and no repeating elements would it be safe to use?  I'd be interested to here when and where those slow downs take place.  Thanks for the feed back!

Comment: No that shouldn't be a problem. The worst case is when you have a lot of data in the scope and additionally the object being watch is a big one with lots of properties. This way angular struggles to check all objects for changes on every $digest cycle. The basic guideline is try to keep the scope light and don't introduce additional watchers unless it's absolutely necessary.